# How to save array value as configuration value in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, arrays, prestashop, smarty

I have an array, for example:

```
[0] => Array
    (
      [id_order_state] => 2
      [name] => Text
    )
```

I want to save this value by using this code, but I can't.

```
Configuration::updateValue('SELECTED_STATUSES', $array);
```

In /classes/Configuration.php I have more information about this:

```
/**
     * Update configuration key and value into database (automatically insert if key does not exist)
     *
     * Values are inserted/updated directly using SQL, because using (Configuration) ObjectModel
     * may not insert values correctly (for example, HTML is escaped, when it should not be).
     * @TODO Fix saving HTML values in Configuration model
     *
     * @param string $key Key
     * @param mixed $values $values is an array if the configuration is multilingual, a single string else.
     * @param bool $html Specify if html is authorized in value
     * @param int $id_shop_group
     * @param int $id_shop
     * @return bool Update result
     */
    public static function updateValue($key, $values, $html = false, $id_shop_group = null, $id_shop = null)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$key** and **$values** are [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) parameters so you can [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array to a string then [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it later

sample code:

```
Configuration::updateValue('SELECTED_STATUSES', serialize($array));
```

Comment: This will not work when your array contains html. Also serialize($array, true) doesn't help. Prestashop sucks if you cannot simply save array with html. You have to first htmlentities() on each array element. And then when retrieving it, after unserialize(), also on each element you have to make html_entity_decode(), then in .tpl you use your variable with the parameter "nofilter". This really shows how Prestashop lacks sometimes in basic logic.